# Agrupar DataFrame por valores únicos de varias columnas combinados

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dispongo del siguiente dataframe correspondiente a datos de transporte de una empres. En el se contemplan fechas trabajadas, el id del conductor que ha trabajado y el almacén o centro desde el que lo ha hecho. Como los conductores pueden rotar entre almacenes y pueden trabajar varias veces en un mismo día, quiero saber cuantos días de trabajo anualmente he tenido en cada centro. Este valor es básicamente la cantidad de días laborales por así decirlo que he tenido al año. Por ejemplo si en un centro tengo en la fecha 22-2-2019 al conductor 1 y al conductor 2, eso contará como 2 días para el cómputo, de igual manera que si tengo al mismo conductor en dos días diferentes también contará como 2. Si un conductor aparece varias veces con la misma fecha, en ese caso contará como un único valor, ya que para mí ha sido un único día laboral.

Un pequeño ejemplo del dataframe sería:

```py
import pandas as pd
fecha = [pd.Timestamp('2018-03-28 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-10-22 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-09 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-12-27 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-12-14 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-01-08 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-11-09 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-12-22 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-10 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-04-10 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-07-12 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-10-18 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-08-24 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-03-19 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-10 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-01-30 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-12 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-08-07 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-12-21 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-01-15 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-12-15 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-11-20 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-11-22 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-04-16 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-01-09 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-10-23 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-01-09 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-07-18 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-11-05 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-10-11 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-05-31 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-01-22 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-04-08 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-12-18 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2019-02-04 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2018-12-18 00:00:00')]

almacen = [7, 6, 3, 6, 1, 102, 6, 1, 103, 6, 3, 3, 103, 103, 103, 101, 7, 3, 7, 1, 6, 101, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 6, 1, 101, 102, 1, 1, 103, 5, 1, 5, 103, 102]

conductor = [7003, 8006, 2055, 8004, 1028, 4019, 8004,1009, 5003, 8006, 2055, 2057, 5002, 5002, 5002, 3002,7006, 2021, 7002, 1006, 8001,3015, 2055, 2055, 1016,1016, 2025, 8003, 1003, 3002, 4028, 1006, 1028, 5003, 8008, 1003, 8008, 5002, 4015]

data = pd.DataFrame({'almacen':almacen,'conductor':conductor,'fecha':fecha})
```

No se cómo podría agrupar esto y contarlo de tal manera que el valor que obtenga sea el que busco. Mi intento ha sido el siguiente:

```py
data.groupby(['almacen',util.fecha.dt.year]).count()
```

pero en este caso no estoy despreciando del conteo los valores de aquellos trabajadores que hayan trabajado en un mismo día varias veces. 
La tabla resultante deberían ser N columnas, una por año, y Z filas, una por cada valor de centro, con el acumulado de estos días en el interior. Gracias.

Una posible solución que he encontrado ha sido ésta:

```py
data['combi'] = data['fecha'].astype(str) + data['conductor'].astype(str)
data.groupby(['almacen',data.fecha.dt.year])['combi'].nunique()
```

Aunque es algo lenta en procesar. Supongo que por usar el str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo he entendido, puedes hacerlo en dos pasos:

- Agrupas por almacén conductor y año y aplicas `nunique` a la columna fecha al completo para solo contar las fechas no duplicadas para un mismo almacén y conductor.
- Vuelves a aplicar `groupby` sobre la salida anterior agrupando por fecha (año) y almacén y aplicas `sum`. Con ello obtienes el total de días trabajados por almacén y año.

---

```
import pandas as pd


fecha = [pd.Timestamp('2018-03-28 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp('2018-03-28 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp('2018-03-28 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp('2018-12-27 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp('2018-12-28 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp('2020-01-08 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp('2018-11-09 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp('2018-11-09 00:00:00'),
         pd.Timestamp('2018-12-10 00:00:00')]

almacen =   [7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6]
conductor = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]

data = pd.DataFrame({'almacen':almacen,'conductor':conductor,'fecha':fecha})

dias_por_cond_y_almacen = data.groupby(
    ['almacen', "conductor", data.fecha.dt.year]
    )["fecha"].nunique()

dias_por_almacen = dias_por_cond_y_almacen.groupby(["almacen", "fecha"]).sum()
```

> ```
> >>> data
>    almacen  conductor      fecha
> 0        7          1 2018-03-28
> 1        7          2 2018-03-28
> 2        7          1 2018-03-28
> 3        6          1 2018-12-27
> 4        6          2 2018-12-28
> 5        7          1 2020-01-08
> 6        6          2 2018-11-09
> 7        6          2 2018-11-09
> 8        6          1 2018-12-10
>
> >>> dias_por_cond_y_almacen
> almacen  conductor  fecha
> 6        1          2018     2
>          2          2018     2
> 7        1          2018     1
>                     2020     1
>          2          2018     1
> Name: fecha, dtype: int64
>
> >>> dias_por_almacen
> almacen  fecha
> 6        2018     4
> 7        2018     2
>          2020     1
> Name: fecha, dtype: int64
> ```

Comment: Si a eso me refería, yo lo hice combinando finalmente las dos columnas mediante strings, pero así tiene mas sentido, lo mío es una chapuza. Muchas gracias.